# phone type in computed property

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

In the following code sample the property type for [MainSwitchBoardPhone] is "Phone". When I make the computed ClinicHospitalAddress property the summary property for the Entity I would like the phone number to show up in a  data entry screen with (555) 555-5555 format rather than merely a string. i.e. 5555555555.  Is there a way to do this?

```
Private Sub ClinicHospitalAddress_Compute(ByRef result As String)
  ' Set result to the desired field value
  result = [ClinicHospital] & " " & [StreetAddress] & ", " & _
           [City] & " " & [MainSwitchBoardPhone]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
result = String.Format("{0} {1}, {2} (###) ###-####" _
    , [ClinicHospital] _
    , [StreetAddress] _
    , [City] _
    , Convert.ToInt64([MainSwitchBoardPhone]) _
    )
```

Edit: Added Convert.ToInt64

Comment: Hi Yann, Here is what I have in the computed property and I get the same result  Thank you.:
Namespace LightSwitchApplication

    Public Class ClinicHospitalLookup

        Private Sub ClinicHospitalAddress_Compute(ByRef result As String)
            ' Set result to the desired field value
            result = String.Format("{0} {1}, {2} (###) ###-####" _
     , [ClinicHospital] _
     , [StreetAddress] _
     , [City] _
     , [MainSwitchBoardPhone] _
     )



        End Sub
    End Class

End Namespace

Comment: Oh!!! Just as I was about to write "that's odd", I realised what's wrong. The #'s are for a numeric value, whereas your phone number must be a string. I could have sworn that you could still use String.Format do this, but after reading around apparently you can't. If MainSwitchBoardPhone is stored with no formatting characters, then you can convert it to a number. Then the code I gave you will work. So use something Like Convert.ToInt64([MainSwitchBoardPhone]), instead of just MainSwitchBoardPhone.

Comment: In LightSwitch I changed the property type for MainSwitchBoard to "Integer" and then `result = [ClinicHospital] & " " & [StreetAddress] & ", " & _
[City] & " " & Format([MainSwitchBoardPhone],"(###) ###-####")
` displayed correctly in the list screen.  This will work for this particular application but the desirable solution would be to have the `Convert.ToInt64` solution employed with the intial "Phone" property type but I could not figure out the correct way to write it.

Comment: I showed you how to use it; "Convert.ToInt64([MainSwitchBoardPhone]), instead of just [MainSwitchBoardPhone]". I've updated my original code to put in in context.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you could do that on this page. However, the result is still the same.  The #'s are still showing up in the computed property on the data entry modal screens and lists.

Comment: The #'s can only be showing up if you're supplying a String value (that's not being converted). If you use the exact code in my answer, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

as follows:

```
result = [ClinicHospital] & " " & [StreetAddress] & ", " & _
```

[City] & " " & Format([MainSwitchBoardPhone],"(###) ###-####")

Comment: Rob, Thank you for responding. However, the #'s are displayed on the form as #'s rather than the phone number.                                                           HospitalName Address, City (###)###-####

Comment: In that case mainswitchboardphone is likely a string, not an integer.  Please change the code to Format(Val([MainSwitchBoardPhone]),"(###) ###-####") and you should be good.